# merge svn feature branch to release branch

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

I have a trunk, from which I created a release branch (and I have done work on it, already committed). After this, I created a feature branch from the trunk, and now I'm ready to reintegrate it in the trunk, using svn merge --reintegrate.

However, I realized that I need all the changes implemented in the feature branch also on the release branch.
In my mind, the command would be

```
svn merge ^/feature_branch release_branch_local_pach
```

and then reintegrate the  feature branch in the trunk

```
cd feature_branch_local_path
svn merge ^/trunk && svn ci -m "sync of feature with trunk"
cd trunk_local_path
svn merge ^/feature_branch --reintegrate && svn ci -m "feature reintegrated in trunk"
```

Is it correct? Do I have to provide some revision number to the first merge command? I use svn 1.8.13, and I have never merged without a --reintegrate.

Comment: You don't need to care about `--reintegrate` any more. The internal problems that led to this flag have already been fixed in 1.8 thus it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if first merge will works always correctly. If you has sync merged from trunk into branch, then them also will be moved into release branch and I suggest it will not be what you want.

May be better strategy will be merge only selected revisions (cherry picking):

```
svn merge -c 100,105,107 ^/feature_branch release_branch_local_pach
```

(where 100,105,107 - revisions which should be merged)

And also, if you want to continue merge from release branch to trunk, you need block cherry pick result revision in trunk. Say you commit cherry pick as revision 120, then

```
svn merge -r 120 ^/release_branch trunk_local_pach --record-only
svn commit -m "Block revison 120 from remerge"
```

In this case next time when yoy try merge release branch into trunk, subversion will not try merge revisions 100, 105, 107 second time (first time they was merged during reintegrate merge)

Comment: Thanks! For future reference: I haven't sync the feature branch with the trunk, so the merge `svn merge -r100:107 ^/feature_branch release_branch_local_pach` worked. But I agree with you that a sum of cherrypicks would be better, and it will allow me to syn the feature branch with the trunk. I was not aware of the --record-only, good to know it. Perhaps I can do the cherrypicks _after_ the reintegration (since in this case the feature branch is almost completed and ready to be reintegrated).